# FIRUser conflicts with Core Data - Swift 4

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I suspect this error is due to a compiler issue in Xcode 9.2...

I am integrating Firebase into my iOS app (right now getting auth working), and since the app relies heavily on users, I have also created a User entity.

However, my code will not compile as it thinks that the `FIRUser` user parameter in the delegate method didSignInWith should be User (core data entity) and not `FIRUser`...

This is obviously wrong, as I want to map from a `FIRUser` on Firebase to a User object on the phone, and just to verify that this conflict is raising the error, I set the codegen on the User entity to none/manual and while that fixed the naming conflict my app no longer "knows" what a User `NSManagedObject` variable is...

How should I go about resolving this? Thanks!

Comment: oh almost forgot, I updated the Xcode command line tools (xcode-select --install)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question, you are having a naming conflict so replacing the parameter in the call with FirebaseAuth.User? instead of just User? so XCode knows which User Class it is.

So intead of

```
func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith user: User?, error: Error?) {
  // handle user and error as necessary
}
```

try

```
func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith user: FirebaseAuth.User?, error: Error?) {
  // handle user and error as necessary
}
```

Let me know if I mis-understood the question.

Comment: Thanks! So that does get rid of the compiler error: 'FIRUser has been renamed User' (which is certainly not true), however now inside the function the compiler still thinks user is of type User, but I need it to be FIRUser so I can extract the relevant information out of it. This was verified with the type(of: ) method. Even if I force cast the object I get this warning: 'Conditional downcasting from 'User?' to 'User' does nothing (if let user = user as? FirebaseAuth.User)

Comment: @user3689341Hold up... It *is* correct that *FIRUser has been renamed User*. That's from Firebase 3 to Firebase 4 and they did that to align the Firebase classes with Swift naming conventions; see [Firebase 4 Migration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/naming-migration-guide). If you are still having errors, update you question to include the updated code, a description of the issue and we'll take a look.

Comment: Wow did not see that! Thanks for pointing out this critical renaming issue. I ended up just renaming my User entity to AppNameUser and now things appear to be working properly. I wanted to avoid doing this but it's not a big issue.

Comment: @user3689341 Good - be sure to read through that migration guide as it has a large impact on Firebase 3 projects. If this answer helped, be sure to accept it so it can help others!